# How to get my app icon into the left down corner of iOS 8 lockscreen?

Tags: ios, ibeacon, lockscreen

Ok, first of all I've been reading a lot of questions and all of them are asking about how to appear in "Recommended Apps" or something like that. I dont want that, for example, when Im near a Starbucks Cofee I get the starbucks app icon on the down left corner of the lockscreen..

Obviously I have the starbucks app installed and everithing, so I want to know how to do that, Im assuming it has to be with iBeacons or something but Im not shure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app uses iBeacon region monitoring or geofence region monitoring then your app icon will be displayed when the device enters a monitored region.

Otherwise, you have no control over the display of your app on the lock screen - Apple uses user behaviour tracking to determine which apps are often used in a particular location and display the appropriate icon.

For example, when I am near a train station the timetable app I have installed is displayed because, presumably, lots of other people use that app in that location.

This is probably the case with the Starbucks app - they aren't monitoring regions for every one of their stores, but rather their customers often use the app in those locations and Apple has observed this m

Comment: Perfect! And iBeacon region monitoring is available for android? Thanks!

Comment: Some versions of android have iBeacon monitoring, but I have never used it